# Unable to spy on third party library function in test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a component that uses a third party library. When the button is clicked, it triggers the library's api.. gets the data from its callback and calls the `this.props.SaveData` with the returned data.

```
const Comp = () => {
    let editorApi: any;

    const triggerSave = () => {
        // call to third party component api 
        editorApi.export((data) => {
            this.props.SaveData(data.values);
        })
    }

    return (
        <>
            <ThirdPartyEditor ref={(editor: any) => editorApi = editor} />
            <button onClick={triggerSave}>Save Data</button>
        </>
    )
}
```

Since I'm testing the `Comp` component, I mocked `third-party-editor` in my test. But now when I try to test that `this.props.SaveData` was called I'm getting this error:

`Cannot spy the export property because it is not a function; undefined given instead`

Test:

```
jest.mock("third-party-editor", () => ({
    default: () => "MyEditor"
}))

test("it calls SaveData when button is clicked", () => {
    const editor = jest.spyOn(ThirdPartyEditor, "export").mockImplementation((data) => );
    const { container, queryByText } = render(<Comp {...props} />);
    act(() => fireEvent.submit(queryByText("Save Data")));
    // fails to find export
})
```

EDIT: Different mocking approach

```
jest.mock("third-party-editor", () => ({
    default: () => {
        return class Mocked {
            public editorApi = jest.fn();
            public export = jest.fn();
            public render() {
                return "Editor";
            }
        };
    },
}));
```

Returns the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'export' of undefined`

Comment: can you show an example?

Comment: sorry, misunderstood how it's mocked.